# Sed in Bash script - replace error cause of variable content

Tags: linux, bash, sed, webdav

I have a Bash script:

```
var="
<Location /webdav/vendor1>
 DAV On
 AuthType Digest
 AuthName "rw"
 AuthUserFile /etc/password/digest-password
 Require user test123456
</Location>

<Location /webdav/limited/vendor1/demo>
 Dav On
 AuthType Digest
 AuthName "ro"
 AuthUserFile /etc/password/digest-password-test2
<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>
deny from all 
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
"

sed -i -e "s/somestringX/${var}/g" change.txt
```

which returns error: sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command

When $var is some single/multi-line  string without special signs like /"'<>, everything works fine.

I guess that the problem is with the content of my $var, but I don't know what to do in order to make it work.

What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sed can also use any character as a separator for the "s" command. Basically, sed takes whatever follows the "s" as the separator.  So you could change your command to something like:

```
sed -i -e "s_somestringX_${var}_g" change.txt
```

You will want to ensure that the delimiter is not part of your target variable.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although I had to change a little my $var in order to make it working. Thanks!

So the working script looks like this:

`#!/bin/bash
var="\n<Location /webdav/vendor1>\nDAV On\nAuthType Digest\nAuthName "rw"\nAuthUserFile /etc/password/digest-password\nRequire user test123456\n</Location>\n\n<Location /webdav/limited/vendor1/demo>\nDav On\nAuthType Digest\nAuthName "ro"\nAuthUserFile /etc/password/digest-password-test2\n<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>\ndeny from all\n</LimitExcept>\n</Location>\n#pokazivac\n"`

sed -i -e "s_#pokazivac_${var}_g" change.txt

Answer (score 2):

You should replace all slashes with escaped slashes, being `\/`. That will do for most texts. If your text will however contain `&`, escape that, too. Any backslashes will have to be escaped as well, as `\\`

As your text doesn't seem to contain any ampersands or backslashes, this should do:

```
sed -i -e "s/somestringX/${var//\//\\\/}/g" change.txt
```

That seems rather complex, but we just replace `/` with `\/`. Bash can do this with `${string//substring/replacement}`, but we have to escape the slashes *and* the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

you could try `awk`

```
awk -v v="$var" '{gsub("somestringX",v); print}' change.txt > newfile.txt
```

The only difference here is it would not modify the `change.txt` file in place as `sed` does with the `-i` option.  It would redirect the result to `newfile.txt`

or if you want to do the same as `sed -i`

```
awk -v v="$var" '{gsub("somestringX",v); print}' change.txt > newfile.txt && mv newfile.txt change.txt
```